# Why all threads get the lock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am just learning multiple-threads in Java.And I am using jdk1.8 .Just encountering `ReentrantLock`'s `tryLock(long timeout,@NotNull java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)`.
The below are my code:

```
public class TimeLock implements Runnable {
    static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (lock.tryLock(4000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " get lock.");
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } else {
                System.out.println("get lock failed");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeLock timeLock = new TimeLock();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(timeLock, "First-Thread");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(timeLock, "Second-Thread");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
  }
```

And my question is: Why all of First-Thread and Second-Thread got the lock?Does not tyrLock() mean trying get the lock in the specified time?

For example, First-Thread get the lock and then hold it for 6 seconds.At the same time Second-Thread will not get the lock in 4 seconds.But the result was not as my logical reasoning.

I just try to use `lock.trylock()` with no parameters, it worked correctly.Thank you advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `lock.tryLock(4000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` statement, you specify 4000 seconds, not 4 seconds

Either change time unit to *TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS* or value to *4* to generate expected use case.

With above change you got below output:

    `First-Thread get lock.
    get lock failed`